# How does VB.NET decide what key is unique in Dictionary(Of)?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have the following class:

```
Public Class Pair(Of T1, T2)

    Public Property First As T1
    Public Property Second As T2

    Public Sub New(Optional ByVal first As T1 = Nothing, Optional ByVal second As T2 = Nothing)
        Me.First = first
        Me.Second = second
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function tostring() As String
        Return String.Format("<[{0},{1}]>", First, Second)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer         
        Return Integer.Parse(String.Format("{0}{1}", First.GetHashCode, Second.GetHashCode))
    End Function
End Class
```

However, when I create a dictionary using Pair as the key:

```
    Dim Pairs as Dictionary(Of Pair(Of Integer, Integer), String)

    Dim p = new Pair(of integer, integer)(1234, 13)
    Dim p2 = new Pair(of integer, integer)(1234, 13)

    console.writeline(String.Format("Hash 1:{0} Hash 2:{1}", p.gethashcode(), p2.gethashcode()))
    Pairs.add(p, "Hello")

    Console.WriteLine(Pairs(p2))
```

My expectation is that since both `p` and `p2` have the hash code of `123413` they would hit the same dictionary element and that the `WriteLine` would display "Hello". What really happens, however, is that I get a `KeyNotFoundException`, which leads me to believe that the `Dictionary (Of...)` doesn't actually use the `GetHashCode` method.

So what do I need to do to make both of these Pairs refer to the same dictionary element?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to override Equals().  GetHashCode is going to blow soon.

Comment: Ultimately, I would question why you are trying to use a Pair(Of T, U) as the Key in your Dictionary in the first place. Are you sure you don't want your string to be the key and the Pair object to be the Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

`GetHashCode` is used by the Dictionary to figure out where to store the key internally, but it's not an exact match scenario. In ideal circumstances, the hash code should map each key to a unique slot index, making lookups extremely quick.

In practice, values in a Dictionary are stored at an index in an array . With 2^32 different types of hash codes, it is infeasible to create an array index for each hash code, so the Dictionary transforms the hash code into an array index where the values are stored. Because of this, the Dictionary experiences what are called "hash collisions". This means that different keys will map to the same hash value.

Dictionary's are good at managing this, but ultimately when two or more hash codes create the same index (which *will* happen when the collection gets big enough), the Equals method must determine which key to use to locate the Key/Value pair that contains the value you are after. If Equals is false for all items in the bucket, then it returns the `KeyNotFoundException` you experienced.

On to the code:

While you could override `Equals`, I don't see why you need to. For starters, I would get rid of your `GetHashCode`. You will eventually have problems with it, as shown here:

```
Dim p = new Pair(of integer, integer)(Int32.MaxValue, Int32.MaxValue)
p.gethashcode() 'BOOM!!!
```

Instead, based on what you are doing here, I'd recommend that you convert your Pair class to a `struct` (Structure in VB), leaving Equals and GetHashCode alone. This is really only a good idea if you are assigning value types (int, byte, bool, etc...) to the Pair because of performance reasons. I would really consider this though.

If you have to have a class, create a representative key that returns a type that is suitable for the Dictionary. For instance, because `KeyValuePair` is a value type, it will be compared based on its value, not a reference.

```
Public Function GetKey() As KeyValuePair(Of T1, T2)        
    Return New KeyValuePair(Of T1, T2)(First, Second)
End Function
```

And your Dictionary becomes

```
Dim Pairs as Dictionary(Of KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer), String)
Pairs.add(p.GetKey(), "Hello")
Console.WriteLine(Pairs(p2.GetKey()))
```

(If there are any syntax errors, it is because I am not a VB programmer.)

Comment: I ended out overriding `Equals` and fixing `GetHashCode` to return the hashcode of the string, instead of the integer.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same hash code isn't enough - the two keys need to be *equal* too, i.e. `key1.Equals(key2)` has to be true (or the equivalent under a custom comparer).

You haven't overridden `Equals`, so two `Pair` objects are always unequal.

(Note that your hash code function will also fail in various ways, such as if they're both negative. Why not just combine the two integer values in some way?)

I don't know VB well enough to come up with the suitable override myself when I ought to be going to bed, but in C# it would be something like:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (other.GetType() != this.GetType())
    {
        return false;
    }
    var otherPair = (Pair<T1, T2>) other;
    return EqualityComparer<T1>.Default(this.First, otherPair.First) &&
           EqualityComparer<T2>.Default(this.Second, otherPair.Second);
}
```

(I'd use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` for the hash code generation too, by the way.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues you have to deal with here.

To start with - you must also override `Equals` as `GetHashCode` is only meant to be a fast method to determine if two objects **are not equal**. It never is meant to tell you if the objects **are equal**. That's what `Equals` is for - it is meant to be the final check that two objects **are equal** and it could be much slower to compute than `GetHashCode`.

Here's an example. Say you have three very long strings, two that are the same length and the other different. If `GetHashCode` returned the length of the strings then you could very quickly determine that the third string is definitely not equal to the first two. You'd have to check the actual contents of the first two to see if they are equal and this could be a lengthy process comparatively.

The next thing, and this is equally important, you **cannot** have a hash code that changes during the lifetime of the object.

The key word is **cannot**. It will break things.

The `Dictionary(Of ,)` class uses a series of "buckets" to quickly find values based on the hash code of the key. So, if your key's hash code changes *after* it was added to the dictionary then the dictionary will not be able to find it and it will allow you to add the key twice!

Here's an example:

```
Dim d = New Dictionary(Of Pair(Of Integer, Integer), String)
Dim p = new Pair(Of Integer, Integer)(10, 11)
d.Add(p, "James")
Dim before = d(p) ' Found!
p.First = 12
Dim after = d(p) ' NOT Found!
```

Or this:

```
Dim d = New Dictionary(Of Pair(Of Integer, Integer), String)
Dim p = new Pair(Of Integer, Integer)(10, 11)
d.Add(p, "James")
p.First = 12
d.Add(p, "Tom") ' ALLOWED!
```

This is why mutable structs are bad.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, technically speaking I *want* the last behavior. In Python I could do this: `mydict = {(123, 45.6): "Hello", ("XR-71", 1337): "Blackbird"}` and Python is perfectly fine with giving me back an (int, float):string, and (string, int):string. Because we have to have `Option Strict` on here, I can't just do Dictionary `(Of Object(), String)`, without an insane amount of `TryParse`'s that might give me incorrect behavior anyways. So when you say break things, do you mean it will only break how you showed me, because that is exactly the behavior I need. If there's a better way, I'll do it!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but as long as your Key properly handles `Equals`, I don't see why you would have problems with Dictionary (Of Object(), String).

Comment: @Wayne - The second behaviour is adding the same key twice and that's what's broken. You can't do that with a dictionary. It now contains two key value pairs each with the same key. Your example in your comment isn't adding the same key twice, it's adding distinct keys of different types. That's a very different behaviour. Paul is right. You could use `Dictionary(Of Object(), String)` or even `Dictionary(Of Object, String)` and it'll work great as long as all of your keys implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals` correctly. Can you explain why you think you'd need to use `TryParse`?

Comment: because _I_ need the values of the keys. When something has been cast as an `Object`, the only way I'm aware of to return it to its native type is via `DirectCast` or one of the `CXXX` forms. Which I don't want to do.

Comment: @Wayne - When living in the VB.NET/C# world you have static typing - you should always have `Option Strict On` set for VB.NET - and that means one of four things to get your key values out. (1) casting, (2) use a common interface/abstraction, (3) reflection, or (4) `dynamic` types. Why do you need to get to the value of the keys?

Comment: @Enigmativity, because I'm sending messages that have composite keys.

Comment: @Wayne - I can see that you have composite keys I just want to know why you need to get the value of the keys out of the dictionary? Obviously you have the key values when you put items into the dictionary, but why do you need to get them out?

Comment: The keys are part of the message. Technically speaking, I could stick them in the value, but I figured that since I'm already passing the data in the form of the keys I could just pull the data right from the keys

Comment: @Wayne - you keep telling me the "what" and not the "why". I think there would be a nice clean alternative, but I don't understand your requirements enough to help. Email me on "james" at my user name dot com if you'd like to discuss further. Cheers.